# How can I make my caption span both columns in a twocolumn revtex document?

Tags: floats, captions, revtex

I'm using revtex with twocolumn. I have a wide figure, and I put it in the `widetext` environment to allow it to span both columns. The figure itself looks fine, but the caption seems to be stuck in one of the columns, instead of following the rest of the figure and spanning the full width of the page.

**How can I get the caption on a figure to span the full width of the page in revtex with two columns?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest you not to use `widetext`, but `figure*` instead; notice that now the figure (and its caption) will span both columns, but the image will appear on the top of the following page:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{some text for the caption of the example figure; it will span at least two lines just for the example; here we add some more text just to make the caption longer}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want to keep the figure in single column but span the caption in two columns?